# Thread management - are threads shut down once done executing?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking at a legacy system and seeing the following code. The `ServiceLifetimeThread` method is started on a separate thread and then it creates new threads in the second `try` block.

My question is what happens with those new threads that are created? Are they shut down once `CheckDeviceStatus` is done executing?

```
private void ServiceLifetimeThread(WaitHandle pleaseStopEvent, object args)
{
    while (!PleaseStopEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            //freeze the lifetime thread on configurable period of time
            pleaseStopEvent.WaitOne(_serviceConfiguration.LifeTimeThreadWakeUpIntervalSeconds /*seconds*/ * 1000 /*milliseconds*/);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log it...
        }

        try
        {
            var deviceIds = GetDeviceIdsToCheckStatus();

            foreach (var deviceId in deviceIds)
            {                        
                //each time start the new thread and send a command to it
                new Thread(CheckDeviceStatus).Start(deviceId);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log it...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they shut down and wiped off once CheckDeviceStatus is done executing (unlike threadpool threads, which return to the pool).

Comment: This code can produce more and more threads, especially when `CheckDeviceStatus` executes longer, than `LifeTimeThreadWakeUpIntervalSeconds` seconds. I'd re-write it.

Comment: Once your threads lifecycle is complete it will be disposed of "gracefully" avoid using Thread.Abort() and allow any threads to finish on their own.

Comment: You can/should keep a reference to your child threads and then call wait() on them, otherwise your main thread might exit before your child threads which would be bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to make a distinction on the word "thread" here I think.
There are two types of "thread going on here (that we're concerned with at least):

1: System.Threading.Thread - an object.
2: CLR (managed) thread.

The `OBJECT` created by calling `new Thread()` will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as `.Start()` finishes being called (eg, the for-loop continues to the next line), and will be destroyed / cleaned up whenever GC decides best *(GC's operating seems like a dark art to me!)*

However, the `.Start()` method will create a new CLR thread. This is NOT affected by the lifetime of the object created above, and thus won't be affected by the garbage collector doing its thang with that object.
Instead, this CLR thread will be destroyed as soon as the method "CheckDeviceStatus" finishes.

This can be altered with calls to the likes of Thread.Abort and some others, but your code sample doesn't make mention of these, nor indicates the use of them, so I haven't gone into that here.

Comment: There will be other references to the `Thread` object when it is created (such as the `Thread.CurrentThread` static variable) that will prevent it from being GCed at least until the thread finishes executing.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure that's true.. Thread.CurrentThread seems to create an object around the current CLR thread. The actual object created by the {new Thread()} call will surely be disposed when it goes out of context, yet the pointer will still exist in the CLR?